# What $\partial^2 u / \partial s^2$ is equal to?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does partial derivative work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235103/how-does-partial-derivative-work)

If $\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}$ is equal to $$e^s \cos(t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + e^s \sin(t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y},$$ what $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial d s^2}$ is equal to?

What expression are we suppose to get? I have been trying to figure out what to do for a hour, but I am quite lost. Doesn't the second partial derivative of $s$, give the same thing?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $\partial ds^2$ looks like a typo. There shouldn't be both a $\partial$ and a $d$.

Comment: That depends. Do $x$ and $y$ depend on $s$?

Comment: Probably you should say what variables are functions of what other variables.  Partial derivatives depend on that information.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial s} (\partial u / \partial s).
$$
In your case $cos(t)$ is considered a constant. We have $u$ a function of $s$, and likewise the derivatives of $u$.

So
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial s} (\partial u / \partial s) \\ &= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial s} (e^s cos(t) \partial u / \partial x + e^s sin(t) \partial u / \partial y)\\ &=  \left[(e^s cos(t) \partial u / \partial x)+ (e^s cos(t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial s\partial x})\right] + \left[(e^s sin(t) \partial u / \partial y) +
(e^s sin(t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s\partial y})\right]
\end{align}
$$
Note that we have used the product rule here since you for example have the product of $e^s$ with the partial derivative of $u$.

Comment: what did you do? how come you have 3 terms instead of 2?

Comment: err it should be s instead of 2

Comment: @Matt. The first term is a product of two functions that depend on $s$, so using the product rule...

Comment: i don't understand what \partial / partial s is suppose to do... is that supposed to be the partial derivative of s?

Comment: but it's the second derivative of s so the trigonometric terms should be considered to be constant variables and not functions. we have f(x) but not g(x). am i wrong?

Comment: btw i made an error, it should be e^s

Comment: @Matthew: I will update

Comment: @Thomas Judging from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/235103/19532), $x$ and $y$ are functions of $s$.

Comment: @Pragabhava: I am a bit confused about this. I will let my answer stand as I feel that it best answers this current question.

Comment: i am even more confused. i couldn't find any video tutorial on this.

Comment: @Matthew: I understand that you are confused. And, as I mentioned elsewhere, I really do think that you just need to study exactly what a partial derivative is and how it is different from a total derivative.