# How does partial derivative work?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I don't understand the second step at all. Where did the $\partial^2 u/ \partial x^2$ come from and why do we have six terms?

Comment: Second step of what? I don't see any numbered steps.

Comment: visit this [search result](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=partial+derivative) and see if any of the questions is of help.

Comment: the step where the 2 terms turn into 6 terms

Comment: I would be helpful if we had more context, e.g. what these variables $s,t,u$ are and their "dependencies". It doesn't help that this is using $\partial y / \partial x$ notation.

Comment: If u=f(x,y) where x=escost and y=essint

show that d2u/dx2+d2u/dy2 = e-2s[d2u/ds2+d2u/dt2

Comment: In both this question and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/235080), there are undefined terms ($x$, $y$, and $t$). To give an answer, it would be useful to know how these relate to $u$ and $s$. Since these questions are quite close, I am going to close the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multivariable chain rule states that, if $x = x(s,t)$, $y = y(s,t)$, and $u = u(x,y)$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
\end{align}
To calculate the second derivatives
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right)\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right)
\end{align}
where the first step is the distribution of the derivative, the second is the product rule for differentiation.

Now,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\right) = \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial s^2}, \qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right) = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial s^2}
$$
and, using the multivaraible chain rule again
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) &= \frac{\partial \left(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial \left(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial \left(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) &= \frac{\partial \left(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial \left(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial \left(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}
\end{align}

Supposing $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x}$ and substituting into $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s^2}$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\right)^2 + 2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right)^2 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial s^2} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial s^2}
$$

Why don't you calculate $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s \partial t}$, $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$ and see if you've improved your understanding?

---

The whole answer:

Let $v(s,t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} e^s \cos t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} e^s \sin t$, where $x = x(s,t)$ and $y = y(s,t)$. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial s} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} e^s \cos t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} e^s \sin t\right)\\
&= \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s \partial x} e^s \cos t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\big(e^s \cos t\big) + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s \partial y} e^s \sin t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\big(e^s \sin t\big)\\
&= \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right) e^s \cos t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}e^s \cos t \\
&\hskip2in + \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right) e^s \sin t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}e^s \sin t
\end{align}
*From* the form of $v$ and your image, I'm assuming $x(s,t) = e^s \cos t$ and $y(s,t) = e^s \sin t$. In such case,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial s} &= \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} e^{2 s}\cos^2 t + 2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} e^{2s} \cos t \sin t + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} e^{2 s}\sin^2 t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}e^s \cos t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}e^s \sin t
\end{align}
Finally, *from the form* of $v$, I think $v(s,t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}$, but that information wasn't provided by the OP.

Comment: ah i didn't know you could apply the differentiation rule to a partial derivative

Comment: @Thomas I was missing a factor of two in the crossed term. Assuming the cross derivatives are the same, it is correct. If not, the term $2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}$ needs to be substituted by $\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x}\right)$

Comment: @Pragabhava: My point is that the so-called multivariable chain rule doesn't tell you how to find the **partial** derivative bu the regular (or total) derivative. The way you have written it, you have only partial derivatives.

Comment: @Thomas Nope. It is a partial derivative allright. See Courant's _Differential and Itegral Calculus_ (vol II. p. 73). **If** $u = u\big(s,t,x(s,t),y(s,t)\big)$, then the _total derivative_ $$\frac{d u}{d s} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \color{red}{+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}}$$

Comment: i plugged in the data, and i don't get the same thing, i get a similar expression, but i don't get the same thing

Comment: the chain rule equation seems to be correct. i got the same thing in my textbook.

Comment: they got $\partial^2 u / \partial x^2$ instead of $\partial^2 u / \partial s^2$

Comment: @Thomas As the answer says, the only way the first calculation is correct is to assume that _all variables_ remain constant. If not, there is no way that is correct. In thermodynamics, the notation should be $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_v = 2x$, so it's clear that the quantity $v$ is _held_ constant (i.e. the pressure).

Comment: @Matthew I've completed the calculation. You should deduce it yourself, and as an excercise, calculate $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s \partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but my feeble mind still has difficulty grasping the concepts.

Comment: @Matthew No problem. I took me a long time to understand it too. If you do lots of excercises (as I did), and read the theorems carefully, eventually you'll get it.

Answer (score 1):

It is chain rule. Just write functions in a vector valued form nad use the chain rule.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: which chain rule are you referring to?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#The_chain_rule_in_higher_dimensions

Comment: i wasn't referring to the first step, my question has nothing to do with the chain rule.

Comment: @Matthew It has *everything* to do with the chain rule. See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/235140/19532) for clarification.